# ¿Que significa esto en python?

Tags: python

Entiendo que board guarda una lista de 9 espacios, y que luego row guarda esos espacios en tres filas, la primer fila es i*3 corresponde a las posiciones 0,1,2, :(i+1) con 3,4,5 y *3 los ultimos 6,7,8

no se de como obtiene los valores 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 esto es parte de un board para un algoritmo # para hacer el juego Tic Tac Toe de este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ext9G7xspg&t=2399s)  Minuto 40:00

```
board = [' ' for _ in range(9)]

for row in [board[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]:
    print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')
```

Me imprime 9 espacios de una matriz 3x3:

| [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |

Estas barritas son los separadores de la matriz

Comment: Ee..... en tú código en ningún momento se imprime algún número :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
board = "123456789"
lista = [board[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]
print(lista)
for row in lista:
    print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')
```

Primero voy a inicializar `board` con un contenido que me permita distinguir cada celda. Recordemos que en Python cadenas y listas son igualmente iterables.

Luego calculo por anticipado la lista que voy a ocupar en el `for`. Así puedo chequear que produce:

```
['123', '456', '789']
```

Revisando la comprensión de listas

```
[board[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]
```

la variable `i` toma los valores 0, 1 y 2, por lo que cada rebanada de lista retorna una sublista de 3 elementos:

```
i    sublista
---------------
0 -> board[0:3]
1 -> board[3:6]
2 -> board[6:9]
```

Dentro del `for` toma cada sublista le aplica un `join` para obtener

```
0 | 1 | 2
```

a lo cual le agrega un par de '|' por ambos costado e imprime, produciendo:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias estaba buscando la manera de como solucionar ese algoritmo